# Unquoting fails to find variable in mutate and map2 when renaming column of data in nested tibble R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr, rlang

Ok, I'm just trying to rename a column inside a nested tibble based on an identifier/character column:

### MWE:

```
library(magrittr)
iris %>% 
  tibble::as_tibble() %>%
  tidyr::nest(-Species) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    Species = as.character(Species),
    data = purrr::map2(data, Species,
                       ~dplyr::rename(.x, !!.y := Sepal.Width)))
```

but this returns the error:

```
Error in quos(..., .named = TRUE) : object '.y' not found
```

I have tried using `ensym` from `rlang` and all sort of combinations of `!!` and `:=` without success.
That is the first tibble in the data column should have the Sepal.Width column renamed to setosa, the second to versicolor, and for the last tibble Sepal.Widht should be renamed to virginica.

Comment: Just remove the colon `.y = Sepal.Width`?

Comment: No since then the column will literally be named .y.

Comment: Right, sorry for the unnecessary noise.

Comment: Actually, it gives me the following error:
`Error: unexpected '=' in:
"    data = purrr::map2(data, Species,
                       ~dplyr::rename(.x, !!.y ="`
Unless I also remove `!!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could switch away from the formula notation:

```
library(magrittr)
irisNest <- iris %>%
  tibble::as_tibble() %>%
  tidyr::nest(-Species) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Species = as.character(Species))

f <- function(x,y) {dplyr::rename(x, !!y := Sepal.Width)}

irisCheck <- dplyr::mutate(irisNest,
              data = purrr::map2(data, Species, f))
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library("tidyverse")

rename_func <- function(data, Species) {
  Species <- as.character(Species)
  data %>%
    rename(!!Species := Sepal.Length)
}

iris2 <- as_tibble(iris) %>%
  nest(-Species) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(
    data = map2(data, Species, rename_func))

iris2 %>% filter(Species == "setosa") %>% unnest() %>% head(1)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 5
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>   Species setosa Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>   <fct>    <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 setosa     5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
iris2 %>% filter(Species == "versicolor") %>% unnest() %>% head(1)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 5
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>   Species    versicolor Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>   <fct>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 versicolor          7         3.2          4.7         1.4
iris2 %>% filter(Species == "virginica") %>% unnest() %>% head(1)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 5
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>   Species   virginica Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>   <fct>         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 virginica       6.3         3.3            6         2.5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: That does not properly name the columns.

Comment: It is actually not clear what column you mean and what name you want to give it.

Comment: It actually is. The names should correspond to the index in the species column,

Comment: `!!` `:=` are rlang notations for naming columns based in characters. That is, if .y is a variable with a character, the column will be named according to that character.